# event.stopPropagation doesn't work for pseud elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a ul element, which has three  li children elements, and the ul ele has a useCapture event handler for click. In the click event handler, I stop the event via: event.stopPropagation(), so far as everything works as expected perfectly: when you click the ul/li, the event will be stoped.

But when I add a pseudo element for ul via css ::after, things work not well for this child pseudo element, when I click the pseudo element, the click event was not stopped, and In the debugger panel of Chrome, I checked the event listener for pseudo element is totally same as the li elements.

Here are my main codes:

```js
document.querySelector('#ul').addEventListener(
  'click',
  e => {
    console.log('clicked')
  },
  false
)
document.querySelector('#ul').addEventListener(
  'click',
  e => {
    e.stopPropagation()
  },
  true
)
```

```css
#ul::after {
  content: 'child';
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list" id="ul">
  <li class="item">foo</li>
  <li class="item">bar</li>
  <li class="item">baz</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Add a `console.log()` statement to the second listener, you'll see that they run in the opposite order when you click on the pseudo-element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because pseudo elements are not the real DOM, events get register to the real DOM that's why it is not working.

Comment: Why does that cause the event listeners to run in a different order?

Comment: Different order means?

Comment: When he clicks on the `ul`, it runs the listener that calls `stopPropagation()` first, which prevents the other one from running. When he clicks on the pseudo-element, it runs it second, so it's too late to stop propagation to the first listener.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I didn't register event to the psedo element directly, the event handler was rregistered to it's parent element, so I get a little confused...

Comment: When ul gets hit, since ul is real DOM so event gets fire. But when pseudo element gets hit, since its not a real DOM, it does not fire event.